# I'm trying to use callback to return a different result (from an array of results) each time

Tags: c#, callback, sequence, moq, xunit

I'm trying to mock a method to return a different result each time it's called.  This mock will be used by in different tests and the number of possible results may vary.  I have been using SetupSequence but it seems like a lot of lines that may not be needed.
For Example

```
MockMethod(result1, result2, ... resultN)
   setup...
     .Returns(result1),
     .Returns(result2),
     ...
     .Returns(resultN);
```

(This DOES work but WOW I should definitely not have to do this in this way)

I'm trying to use Callback such that it increments and returns the result from an array.
For Example

```
MockMethod(string[] result)
  int callNumber = 0;
  Setup...
     .Callback(() => callNumber++)
     .ReturnsAsync(() => result[callNumber]);
```

But it's returning the first result each time. (I do realize I need to initialize as -1 if it's going to increment before the first return but it doesn't seem to be incrementing at this point anyway.)  The mock is initializing before running the method being tested so I assume that's why it's just returning the first result.  I can't figure out another way to do this without a bunch of return lines. Anybody have any ideas.

I also tried the return first but same result....
For Example

```
MockMethod(string[] result)
  int callNumber = 0;
  Setup...
     .Returns(result[callNumber]);
     .Callback(() => callNumber++)
```